# Exporting HOC component along withStyles MUI

Tags: reactjs

I am creating an app using React and Material UI and I want to export an error boundary HOC that also has styles.

This is my code:

```
import {
  Box,
  Button,
  Container,
  createStyles,
  Theme,
  Typography,
  WithStyles,
} from '@material-ui/core';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';
import flowRight from 'lodash/flowRight';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
interface State {
  hasError: boolean;
}

const styles = (theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    root: {
      padding: theme.spacing(2, 0),
    },
  });

type WrapperProps = WithStyles<typeof styles>;

const withErrorBoundary = <P extends {}>(WrappedComponent: React.ComponentType<P>) => {
  type Props = P & WrapperProps;

  return (properties: Props) =>
    class ErrorBoundary extends Component<Props, State> {
      public static getDerivedStateFromError(error: any) {
        return { hasError: true };
      }

      constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { hasError: false };
      }

      public componentDidCatch(error: any, errorInfo: any) {
        console.error(error, errorInfo);
      }

      public onBackClick() {
        window.location.reload();
      }

      public render() {
        const { classes, ...props } = this.props;

        if (this.state.hasError) {
          return (
            <Container className={classes.root}>
              <Box
                display='flex'
                flexDirection='column'
                justifyContent='center'
                alignContent='center'
              >
                <Typography color='primary' variant='h4'>
                  Ops, ocorreu um erro inexperado. Clique abaixo para voltar.
                </Typography>
                <Button color='primary' variant='contained' onClick={this.onBackClick}>
                  Tentar novamente
                </Button>
              </Box>
            </Container>
          );
        }

        return <WrappedComponent {...(props as P)} />;
      }
    };
};

export default flowRight(
  withStyles(styles),
  withErrorBoundary
);
```

I wanted to use a HOC to make it easy to add it to my routes:

```
<Route
    exact={true}
    path='/:id/home'
    component={withErrorBoundary(HomeContainer)}
/>
```

But when I execute my code I get this error:

```
index.js:1375 Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.
    in Unknown (created by WithStyles(Component))
    in WithStyles(Component) (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Route (at src/index.tsx:40)
    in Switch (at src/index.tsx:36)
    in ThemeProvider (at theme-handler.tsx:50)
    in ThemeHandler (at src/index.tsx:35)
    in Suspense (at src/index.tsx:34)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (at src/index.tsx:33)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A higher-order component is a function that takes a component and returns **a new component.**

Your HOC is a function that returns a function that returns a component.

You can just return the class directly inside the HOC:

```
const withErrorBoundary = <P extends {}>(
  WrappedComponent: React.ComponentType<P>,
) => {
  type Props = P & WrapperProps;

  return class ErrorBoundary extends Component<Props, State> {
    public static getDerivedStateFromError(error: any) {
      return { hasError: true };
    }

    constructor(props: Props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { hasError: false };
    }

    public componentDidCatch(error: any, errorInfo: any) {
      console.error(error, errorInfo);
    }

    public onBackClick() {
      window.location.reload();
    }

    public render() {
      const { classes, ...props } = this.props;

      if (this.state.hasError) {
        return (
          <Container className={classes.root}>
            <Box
              display="flex"
              flexDirection="column"
              justifyContent="center"
              alignContent="center"
            >
              <Typography color="primary" variant="h4">
                Ops, ocorreu um erro inexperado. Clique abaixo para voltar.
              </Typography>
              <Button
                color="primary"
                variant="contained"
                onClick={this.onBackClick}
              >
                Tentar novamente
              </Button>
            </Box>
          </Container>
        );
      }

      return <WrappedComponent {...(props as P)} />;
    }
  };
};
```